# what are the networking features available in iphone?

Tags: iphone, networking

So far I couldn't find anything on google so I'm asking here:

I need to connect two iphones or more to each other for a multiplayer game, what features does iphone api provide? is there some kind of bluetooth device or equivalent in iphone or should i just search over the wireless network connection? and what api should I use to connect them? is it possible to use c++ or are the api functions only available via obj-c iphone sdk?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Apple's Game Kit and Game Center frameworks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) include Objective-C classes for online matchmaking and local Bluetooth games as well.  You should probably start with those.

Comment: if I use Gamekit, is there any chance that if I wanted later I could add support for other platforms (like android) to my game, I mean will an android user be able to play with an iphone user?

Comment: Using Apple's off the shelf solutions isn't going to give you a mechanism to connect to non-iOS devices.  For that you'll want to roll your own mechanism using sockets or something.

Comment: Given Apple's typically policies, no way in hell, Gajet.

Comment: Use iOs sdk for iOs bluetooth or Gamecenter may be easiest ( initiating device plays host ), but if you want x-platform or large persistent worlds then you will be needing your own servers or user-setup servers. Nothing wrong with doing that.